# What does this symbol mean in bayesian estimator example?

Tags: statistics, notation, bayesian, estimation, parameter-estimation

Is this symbol equivalent to 'multiplication', or equivalent to 'equal'?

[image]

Comment: The symbol $\propto$ (read as "proportional to") is used when the 'kernel' of a density function is given without the 'norming constant' that makes the density integrate to unity over its support. For example (as in the passage you quote), if $\theta \sim \mathsf{Beta}(5,6),$ one might say that the likelihood function (given specific data) is $ \propto \theta^4(1-\theta)^5.$ [Be careful not to confuse $\propto$ with Greek letter $\alpha$ or with infinity $\infty.]$

Comment: In JaX the symbol $\propto$ is coded as `$\propto$`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$\propto$ means "directly proportional".

Mathematically speaking, $a \propto b \implies a = kb$, where $k$ is non-zero constant.

Comment: Thanks! I understand

Comment: Certainly $a=kb\implies a\propto b$ but not necessarily the other way around.  To many authors this is in reference just to end-behavior.

Comment: In context, this answer may be clear enough, However, it is much too broadly stated. This notation is mainly used in Bayesian statistics, as in the passage quoted in the Question.